# How do you find the unicode value of a character in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm looking for something like Python's `ord(char)` for Julia that returns an integer.

Comment: @Asadefa Okay, but that question has been asked, answered, and archived many times over for the older, more popular languages. This is Julia (8ys old), not C (48y) or C++ (35y). I am having difficulty understanding why this comment was posted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`codepoint`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.codepoint). From the documentation:

> `codepoint(c::AbstractChar) -> Integer`
>
> Return the Unicode codepoint (an unsigned integer) corresponding to the character `c` (or throw an exception if c does not represent a valid character). For `Char`, this is a `UInt32` value, but `AbstractChar` types that represent only a subset of Unicode may return a different-sized integer (e.g. `UInt8`).

For example:

```
julia> codepoint('a')
0x00000061
```

To get the exact equivalent of Python's `ord` function, you might want to convert the result to a signed integer:

```
julia> Int(codepoint('a'))
97
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also just do:

```
julia> Int('a')
97
```

If you have a String:

```
julia> s="hello";

julia> Int(s[1])
104

julia> Int(s[2])
101

julia> Int(s[5])
111
```

More details [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Strings_and_characters#Converting_characters_to_integers_and_back_again).

Comment: Just to point out that `Int('a')` suggested here is exactly equivalent to `Int(codepoint('a'))`, and also shorter.